# Only choosing oldest date (BigQuery)

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I'd like to only choose the oldest date. Using Max/Min doesn't work because it's at row level, and I couldn't figure out a way to use over or NTH as this query will be run each day with a different number of server, w_id and z_id.

The following query:

```
select server, w_id, z_id, date(datetime) as day
from( SELECT server, w_id, datetime, demand.b_id as id, demand.c_type, z_id,
    FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(v3_data.v3_,DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"),
           DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))
    where demand.b_id is not null and  demand.c_type = 'rtb'
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
    having datetime >=  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day")
)
group by 1,2,3,4
having count(day)<2
order by z_id, day
```

Gives results:

```
Row server     w_id  z_id     day
1     A         722  1837  2016-04-19
2     SPORTS     51  2534  2016-04-19
3     A        1002  2546  2016-04-18
4     A        1303  3226  2016-04-19
5     A        1677  4369  2016-04-18
6     NEW     13608  9370  2016-04-19
```

So from the above I'd only like 2016-04-18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions have been helpful, but I believe neither worked the way I wanted and the following does:

```
select server, w_id, id, demand.c_type,z_id,

NTH(1, day) First, NTH(2, day) Second, 

from(

SELECT
      server,
      w_id,
      DATE(datetime) as day,
      demand.b_id AS id,
      demand.c_type,
      z_id,

FROM
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE([black-beach-789:v3_data.v3_],DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))

WHERE
      demand.b_id IS NOT NULL

AND demand.c_type = 'rtb'

AND DATE(datetime) >= DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"))

GROUP BY
      1,2,3,4,5,6

order by day
      )

group by 1,2,3,4,5

having first = date(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day")) and Second is null
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a GROUP_CONCAT might get the job done quite simply here:

```
SELECT
  server,
  w_id,
  z_id,
  day,
FROM (
  SELECT
    server,
    w_id,
    z_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(day) day,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      server,
      w_id,
      DATE(datetime) day,
      demand.b_id AS id,
      demand.c_type,
      z_id,
    FROM
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE(v3_data.v3_,DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))
    WHERE
      demand.b_id IS NOT NULL
      AND demand.c_type = 'rtb'
      AND DATE(datetime) >= DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"))
    GROUP BY
      1,2,3,4,5,6
    ORDER BY
      day) # Critical to order this dimension to make the GROUP_CONCAT permutations unique
  GROUP BY
    server,
    w_id,
    z_id,
    # day is aggregated in GROUP_CONCAT and so it does not get included in the GROUP BY
    )
WHERE
  day = DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"))
```

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks as group_concat will come in handy in the future. I believe my edit works and was simple.

Comment: Removing demand.b_id got your query to match the one in my edit. I only wanted to see when z_id stopped participating in rtb and b_id wasn't essential in the end. Think having multiple b_id for each z_id gave false positive/false negatives and messed up the query.

Answer (score 1):

Most inner select is your untouched original one
The rest is wrapper taking care of min_day
Not tested - as done on go - but at least should give you an idea

```
SELECT server, w_id, z_id, [day]
FROM (
  SELECT server, w_id, z_id, [day], MIN([day]) OVER() AS min_day               
  FROM (                                                  
    SELECT server, w_id, z_id, DATE(datetime) AS [day]
    FROM ( 
      SELECT server, w_id, datetime, demand.b_id AS id, demand.c_type, z_id,
      FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(v3_data.v3_,DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day"), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"day"))
      WHERE demand.b_id IS NOT NULL AND demand.c_type = 'rtb'
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
      HAVING datetime >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-2,"day") 
    )
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    HAVING COUNT([day])<2
  )                                                       
)                                                       
WHERE [day] = min_day                                     
ORDER BY z_id, [day]
```

Comment: I think the edit I made works, yours did not, however its helped me for future window functions.